# How am I able to make my website more interactive between two users?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Scenario: The first person (member) is going to register:

[image]

And the second person (admin) will confirm the request of the member: 
[image]

I want to automatically count the request of the member as 1 without refreshing or something,
How to make my website more interactive between two users?

Comment: You can trigger a jQuery request after each required seconds/minutes to check any incoming request and send data which include register user details on 2nd user to 1st person.

Comment: i know it is possible but it is advisable to perform it like it's gonna refreshes the admin page every 5 seconds. Or every time there will be a request from the member then it gonna trigger the admin page to reload using jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a script that uses ajax to hit a defined url every second and gets the data you need, ou use something quite new and advanced called [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org).
Of course, you can always use a framework that does it for you, but it's always good to know what's going on under the hood.

-------- EDIT --------

You need to use ajax in both pages. In one page, for the user to send the request and store it to the DB, and in the admin page for it to hit every second some URL that returns the number of open requests, so you can load the admin page once and keep hitting this url to know if the number of open requests have changed since you loaded the page. If so, you update the info or do whatever ou need, without refreshing the page.

Comment: i already used ajax to hit defined url and call it back to my desired page to the member page. but it doesn't affect the other tab where my admin account has login, does the session also affects it?